# Перебор всех вариантов чисел составленных из цифр данного числа

Tags: python

Попалась задача: получить множество чисел, составленных из цифр данного числа. Например, из числа `513` можно получить `{135,153,315,351,513,531}`, но, например `533` получить нельзя, т.е. надо просто переставлять цифры. Как это лучше написать на python?

Comment: Читайте про itertools

Answer (score 0):

используйте `itertools.permutations`

```
import itertools


for i in itertools.permutations(input()):
    print(*i,sep='')
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло